# Display date in portuguese locales

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have two dates start and end date.I want to show the dates in portuguese locales.
in config->app.php

```
'locale' => 'pt-br',
```

```
<p>@php echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime($eventDetails->startDate));@endphp  - 
   @php echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime($eventDetails->endDate));@endphp</p>
```

i need to print the date in :
De 27 a 30 de Maio de 2020

Comment: hello,anyone please help me to correct this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR");

$startdate = strftime('%e', $eventDetails->startDate);
$enddate = strftime('%e %B %G', $eventDetails->endDate);

echo "De ".$startdate." a ".$enddate;
```

You can find more information about formatting your the strftime function here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: i need to translate in portuguese the month also

Comment: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: /home/admin/web/thirdangleconstruction.com/public_html/event-management/resources/views/preview.blade.php)

Comment: What is the format of your $eventDetails->startDate variable